# Nested parenthesis automatic indentation in equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, indentation, nesting

Here is some code that produces a display equation with nested parentheses indented to different depths.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(\exists d)
    &\biggl(
        l'(u,d)
        \wedge l'(v,d)
        \wedge
        \bigl(\forall z\bigr)
        \bigl(l'(z,d)\to(z=u\vee z=v)\bigr)\\
    &\hspace{34pt}\begin{array}{rl}
            \wedge~
            (\exists p)(\exists q)
                &\Bigl(
                    cod(p)=d\wedge cod(q)=d
                    \wedge l'\bigl(dom(p),d\bigr)
                    \wedge l'\bigl(dom(q),d\bigr)\\
                &\hspace{49pt}\begin{array}{rl}
                            \wedge~
                            (\forall t)
                                &\Bigl(
                                    \bigl( cod(t)=d\wedge
                                    l'(dom(t),d)\bigr)\\
                                &\hspace{33pt}\to\bigl(t=p\vee t=q\bigr)\\
                                &\hspace{7pt}\Bigr)
                            \end{array}\\
                        &\hspace{7pt}\Bigr)
                    \end{array}
\\&\hspace{7pt}\biggr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there an environment that can automatically handle parenthesis indentation like this? If not, is there a way to automate the indentation of parentheses so that the it does not need to be handled manually in this way? Thanks.

Comment: It appears that alignment is performed, alternatingly, on parentheses and `\wedge` symbols.  Is this impression correct? Separately, the terms `cod` and `dom` May be "operators" and thus should be typeset using upright letters; is this the case?

Comment: Remember, you can use other parentheses/brackets too, to get more visual variation without sizes running wild.  Depending on context `[...{...(...)...}...]` may be usable.

Comment: @Mico -- that is correct, this example involves alternating indentation of parentheses and `\wedge` symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a fully automatic solution, but with code that's quite a bit simpler than in your posting. It uses only one type of alignment structure: `aligned`. The environment is used to perform alignment on both parentheses and on `\wedge` symbols.

The positioning of the closing large parentheses is fine-tuned using `\mkern` ("math-mode kern") directives. I also suggest setting "cod" and "dom" in an upright font if they're "operators".

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cod}{cod}
\begin{document}
\[
(\exists d)
\begin{aligned}[t]
   &\biggl(
      l'(u,d)
      \begin{aligned}[t]
         &\wedge l'(v,d)
            \wedge \bigl(\forall z\bigr)
            \bigl(l'(z,d)\to(z=u\vee z=v)\bigr)\\
         &\wedge (\exists p)(\exists q)
         \begin{aligned}[t]
            &\Bigl( \cod(p)=d
            \begin{aligned}[t]
               &\wedge \cod(q)=d
                    \wedge l'\bigl(\dom(p),d\bigr)
                    \wedge l'\bigl(\dom(q),d\bigr)\\
               &\wedge (\forall t)
               \begin{aligned}[t]
                  &\Bigl( \bigl( \cod(t)=d\wedge l'(\dom(t),d)\bigr)\\
                  &\qquad\qquad \to\bigl(t=p\vee t=q\bigr)\\
                  &\mkern2mu\Bigr)
               \end{aligned}\\
            \end{aligned}\\
            &\mkern2mu\Bigr)
         \end{aligned}\\
      \end{aligned}\\
   &\mkern2.5mu\biggr)
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```